# Colors that change overtime in a canvas (js) / Trouble with setInterval

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, colors, setinterval

I am trying to make an animation in a canvas where there's just a solid rectangle that shifts from white to red to green to blue and then white again. I think the colors work fine but it happens way too fast to even see anything, so I searched for a wait or delay option and came across the setInterval method. I tried everything I could to make it work but with no luck:

Here's the somewhat clean code I made.

The HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      canvas { border: 3px solid black; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="draw()">Start the gradient</button><br><br>
    <canvas id="can" width="200" heigth="200"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript :

```
function draw() {
  var can = document.getElementById('can');
  if (can.getContext) {
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    var r = 0;
    var g = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<255;i++){
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
          r = r + 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<255;i++){
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
          r = r - 1;
          g = g + 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<255;i++){
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
          g = g - 1;
          b = b + 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<255;i++){
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
          r = r + 1;
          g = g + 1;
    }
  }
//'can' is the canvas//
//Red->Green->Blue//
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `setInterval`?

Comment: @FrankModica I tried many things with setInterval but from what I could gather, the form that makes the most sense to me is this :  for(i=0;i<255;i++){  
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';  
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);  
          var x = setInterval(r = r + 1, 15);  
    }I also tried to put the _r = r + 1_ part as a function and use it in setInterval instead but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way. You set up a bunch of timeouts at the beginning:

```
function draw() {
    var can = document.getElementById('can');
    if (can.getContext) {
        var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
        var r = 0;
        var g = 0;
        var b = 0;
        var i;
        var numColors = 255;
        var delay = 0; // ms
        var delta = 5; // ms

        for (i = 0; i < numColors; i++) {
            delay += delta;
            setTimeout(function () {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
                r = r + 1;
            }, delay);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < numColors; i++) {
            delay += delta;
            setTimeout(function () {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
                r = r - 1;
                g = g + 1;
            }, delay);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < numColors; i++) {
            delay += delta;
            setTimeout(function () {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
                g = g - 1;
                b = b + 1;
            }, delay);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < numColors; i++) {
            delay += delta;
            setTimeout(function () {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
                r = r + 1;
                g = g + 1;
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! But is there a way to make it go through a whole palette instead of instantly switching colors ? Sorry for asking again but I have no idea how the last portion works so...

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, let me try again

Comment: Thank you so SO much !!! I was struggling real bad. I'm gonna study how you did it in order to understand. I didn't know I could use setTimeout instead. Thanks a bunch !

Comment: You're welcome. I made another edit just to clean it up and remove some hard-coded numbers.

Comment: In a `setInterval` approach, when each interval is over you then set up the next function call. In the approach here, we just set up a bunch of function calls ahead of time, which will fire at times we calculate up front.

Answer (score 1):

What you are dealing with, is the basics of how does an animation work.

For an animation to work, you need, as un unordered list,

- **a scene**, with some elements that the viewer should be able to identify like personas, or in your case, a solid color.
- **a renderer**, which will well render your scene to some graphic form. Could be an hand drawing on the corner of a notebook in case of a low-end flip-book, or a drawing function in case of computer graphics.
- **a motion engine**, Something that will update the position of our moving elements in the *scene*, and present the next rendered graphics, ticked in a certain time interval. A swipe of a finger in a flipbook, some time based methods in computer graphics. `setInterval` is one such method, but better start directly with the right tool, so let me introduce to you [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which is the defacto best way of powering graphical animations in a browser. Basically, it will schedule a callback function before the next screen refresh, allowing always in-sync animations with the best power economy.

---

So let's build it ;)

Our scene's elements in your case may just be the three components of the solid color we will animate:

```
const color = [255, 255, 255]; // [red, green, blue]
```

The renderer will take of animating it. 
Since your setup has some *key-frames*, what it has to do is to calculate the *in-between* frames. Here I will just show a basic frame increment engine, but it would be better to use a time-based one, but I thought it might be too much for now...

So we will hold a position variable, here after called `currentFrame` so we can know where in the animation we are, from which key-frame to which other one we are going, and calculate the correct values for our in-between frame. At each iteration (each frame) we will increment this variable until we reach the total number of frames our animation will be made of. At this point, we will be able to make it start again by using the modulo `%` operator.

```js
const color = [255, 255, 255]; // [red, green, blue]
const keyFrames = [
  [255, 255, 255], // white
  [255, 0, 0], // to red
  [0, 255, 0], // to green
  [0, 0, 255] // to blue
];
const duration = 5; // in seconds
const totalFrames = 60 * duration; // 60 FPS
let currentFrame = 0;

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function update() {
  // update currentFrame, relative to the whole animation duration
  currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % totalFrames;
  // make it relative to our key-frames
  const keyFrameIndex = currentFrame / (totalFrames / keyFrames.length);
  // Now we know our previous and next key-frames
  const prev = keyFrames[Math.floor(keyFrameIndex) % keyFrames.length];
  const next = keyFrames[Math.ceil(keyFrameIndex) % keyFrames.length];
  // We need to get the in-between ratio (that's the decimal of our floating index)
  const inBetweenRatio = keyFrameIndex - Math.floor(keyFrameIndex);
  //now we can update our color
  calculateInBetween(color, prev, next, inBetweenRatio);
}

function calculateInBetween(color, prev, next, ratio) {
  // simply update each channel of our current color
  color[0] = Math.floor((next[0] - prev[0]) * ratio) + prev[0];
  color[1] = Math.floor((next[1] - prev[1]) * ratio) + prev[1];
  color[2] = Math.floor((next[2] - prev[2]) * ratio) + prev[2];
}

function draw() {
  // clear all
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // render
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color + ")";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
}

// our animation loop
function anim() {
  // update the scene
  update();
  // then render it
  draw();
  // start again at next screen refresh
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}


// let's begin
anim();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```